# jQuery UI Accordion - How to remove style completly?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

I love the functionality of the jQuery accordion (http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/) however I do not want the style !!

I'd like to get rid of all the styles, the img, the border, the color, etc...

I don't see an option for this, this is something they should add. Or I am mistaking?

Comment: if you want you can overwrite in your css,

Comment: seems like there's no built-in way to do this. that's a pity though - would make perfectly sense to me to have an option like 'theming:false'

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can make your own accordion.  Using the jQuery accordion without the UI is pointless.  Creating your own accordion adapted to your site is kind of easy.  You just need to fix the way you want to build it...let's say:

```
<div id='container'>
  <a href='javascript:;'>First link</a>
  <div class='content'>  SOME CONTENT HERE </div>
  <a href='javascript:;'>Second link</a>
  <div class='content'>  SOME CONTENT HERE </div>
  ...
</div>
```

Then, you just need to make something like

```
//On click any <a> within the container
$('#container a').click(function(e) {
        //Close all <div> but the <div> right after the clicked <a>
    $(e.target).next('div').siblings('div').slideUp();
        //Toggle open/close on the <div> after the <a>, opening it if not open.
        $(e.target).next('div').slideToggle();
});
```

You can now edit your class as you want since you actually don't need them for the JavaScript.
Note that the  with the class 'content' can contain whatever you want, including , other  or  since the .siblings and .next only apply to the same hierarchy.

Comment: I made a jsFiddle with your code (and added a bit) and it works wonderfully. http://jsfiddle.net/sikodelika/2Cazf/ --Thanks.

Comment: Just for information, this answer wont handle `collapsible: true` option of accordion.

Comment: It is collapsible as it is. If you dont want it collapsible, you can just comment out that line: $(e.target).next('div').siblings('div').slideUp();

Comment: @yaz what happened? that link doesnt work. This is the link: http://jsfiddle.net/2Cazf/

Answer (score 3):

If your'e not interested in the ui-theme (like me) then don't include the theme  css files

Comment: doesnt this pose problems when things rely on the css-framework to provide parts of the functionality? (im thinikng of `.ui-helper-*` classes in particular)?

Comment: if your using those helper classes for js: they will still be there (and be usefull for your own styling) but if your site in general is using a theme the you going to need to listen to prodigitalson

Comment: In this case you can put your accordion within a <div> tag with a specific id and override the styles for that id:

Comment: Well, if we only need the 'behaviors' and not the 'styles', excluding the jQuery theme CSS makes sense though. jQuery should support **'Concerns Separation'** concept by making the theme CSS 100% optional in order for all behaviors to work without the styling effects. Optionally, they should offer custom CSS classes as parameters to overwrite the optional default styles, namely, **'Style only when exists'**.

Answer (score 3):

I needed (wanted) to do the same thing.  In my case I wanted to remove the extra padding the default css provides for accordion-content, which looks like this:

```
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content { padding: 1em 2.2em; border-top: 0; margin-top: -2px; position: relative; top: 1px; margin-bottom: 2px; overflow: auto; display: none; zoom: 1; }
```

In **MY** css I simply added this:

```
 .ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content {padding: 0;}
```

This successfully set (overrode) just the padding.

Rob

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have already solved the problem since you wrote in 2010.
By the way, now it's possible to avoid styling of each ui widget by control panel, in the official jqueryUI website, before download the theme.

http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

In case of Accordion, just 'uncheck' the checkbox button 'Accordion' and download the generated file.

It's quite late to answer I know but I think it could be useful... just in case :)

Answer (score 1):

You dont generally do this via js thats why ther eis no option. You override the css. Check out the base [css file](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.6/themes/base/jquery-ui.css) and search for `.ui-accordian`.. there will also be styles scoped to some geenral `.ui-widget` classes you need to override. I usually load it up in Firebug and take a look at whats being applied so i know everything i need to overried to give it my look and feel.

Answer (score 0):

Forget all theese tricks, overrides or other pains.

You just have to provide a css scope when you donwload your theme, like:
.jquerythemeon

and then put the class to all elements you want to be themed

EDIT:
I got some bugs with scope today, in structure.min.css the scope was always generated with "jquerythemeon" and not ".jquerythemeon". To fix it just replace all occurences

Answer (score -10):

To remove default style use clearStyle option:

```
 $( ".selector" ).accordion({ clearStyle: true });
```

Comment: That's doesn't work for me, it's still has the ui-theme, how to remove any theme?

Comment: That only clears the defaults widths and height for the element. it's not for clearing the jquery theming.