# Getting jQuery to work with if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pretty new to jQuery so I'm trying to get working a small piece of code.
I'm trying to create sort of an accordion menu.

First, (after looking at some tutorials) I did something very similar to what I wanted:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".content").hide();
    mainmenu();
});

function mainmenu(){        
    $(".option").click(function(){
            $(".content").slideUp("slow");
            $(this).children("div.content").slideDown("slow");
    });
}
```

It worked fine but it did the "hide" + "show" animation if I clicked an opened option.

So, I tried to add a condition to get the menu doing what I wanted, but it doesn't work. Even the content hiding at the begining now doesn't work.

The piece of code that now doesn't work is this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".content").hide();
    mainmenu();
});

function mainmenu(){        
    $(".option").click(function(){
            if (($(this).children("div.content").is(":hidden")){
                $(".content").slideUp("slow");
                $(this).children("div.content").slideDown("slow");
            }else{
                $(".content").slideUp("slow");
            }
    });
}
```

So, if the content is not hidden, it should just hide the content instead of hide and show again.

I don't know if I'm approaching the problem in a bad way or what. I'm very new to this.

If somebody can help me, I will really appreciate it.

Thanks.

**EDIT: I missed one parenthesis at the if statement. It's now working! BTW thank you very much**

Comment: What does not work? What happens? *Edit: I think you can safely delete this question ;)*

Comment: I've seen the problem by myself now, i was missing one ')' at the end of the IF

Comment: ah, right. added my answer before seeing your edit, sry:)

Comment: I can't delete it since i'm with an OpenID, sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a typo.

`if (($(this).children("div.content").is(":hidden")){`

should be

`if ($(this).children("div.content").is(":hidden")){`

Answer (score 0):

You could use ".slideToggle()" which does exactly the same as slideUp() or slideDown().   Another thing you could do is close all other content div when you open one, using the .siblings() method.  See [jQuery UI Accordion - How to remove style completly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287225/jquery-ui-accordion-how-to-remove-style-completly/5450662#5450662) for more details.  I gave an example of jQuery AND HTML structure.